# Webpack: assets for node modules not resolved from dll

Tags: dll, webpack, font-awesome

I have split my application into an application module and a *dll* module for the vendor (`node_modules`) dependencies. *It is an asp.net core application with angular2 on top*

The app seems to load most vendor modules just fine (provided I have actually added them to the vendor dll), but I am having some issues with `font-awesome` and `bootstrap-colorpicker`. Their assets (images and fonts) are not resolved when I use `DllReferencePlugin`. I can only get it to work if I include loaders for `node_modules` for fonts and images in the client app as well.

However, this means that `font-awesome` and `bootstrap-colorpicker` are now part of my application bundle...

I would like to be able to keep them in the vendor bundle/dll. In the code below, I commented out the aforementioned inclusion of the `node_modules` in the client bundle:

```
/*
{
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)(\?.*$|$)/,
    include: [
        helpers.root('node_modules','font-awesome'),
        helpers.root('node_modules','bootstrap')
    ],
    loader: 'file?name=vendor-missing/[name].[hash].[ext]'
},*/
```

But now I receive errors during the webpack build:

```
...
[12] ./~/css-loader!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/sass-loader?sourceMap!./app/scss/application.scss 371 kB {0} [built] [5 errors]
[13] ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 1.46 kB {0} [built]
[14] ./~/css-loader!./~/nouislider/distribute/nouislider.min.css 3.65 kB {0} [built]
[15] ./~/css-loader!./~/bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css 4.27 kB {0} [built] [5 errors]
[16] ./~/bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/img/bootstrap-colorpicker/saturation.png 0 bytes [built] [failed]
[17] ./~/bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/img/bootstrap-colorpicker/hue.png 0 bytes [built] [failed]
[18] ./~/bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/img/bootstrap-colorpicker/alpha.png 0 bytes [built] [failed]
[19] ./~/bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/img/bootstrap-colorpicker/hue-horizontal.png 0 bytes [built] [failed]
[20] ./~/bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/img/bootstrap-colorpicker/alpha-horizontal.png 0 bytes [built] [failed]
[21] ./~/css-loader!./~/ng2-dnd/bundles/style.css 594 bytes {0} [built]
[22] ./~/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot 0 bytes [built] [failed]
[23] ./~/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2 0 bytes [built] [failed]
[24] ./~/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff 0 bytes [built] [failed]
[25] ./~/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf 0 bytes [built] [failed]
[26] ./~/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg 0 bytes [built] [failed]
...
    + 40 hidden modules

   ERROR in ./~/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot
   Module parse failed: C:\path\to\my\app\node_modules\font-awesome\fonts\fontawesome-webfont.eot Unexpected character '�' (1:1)
   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
   SyntaxError: Unexpected character '�' (1:1)
       at Parser.pp$4.raise (C:\path\to\my\app\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15)
       at Parser.pp$7.getTokenFromCode (C:\path\to\my\app\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2756:10)
       at Parser.pp$7.readToken (C:\path\to\my\app\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2477:17)
       at Parser.pp$7.nextToken (C:\path\to\my\app\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2468:15)
       at Parser.pp$7.next (C:\path\to\my\app\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2413:10)
       at Parser.pp$3.parseIdent (C:\path\to\my\app\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2191:10)
       at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (C:\path\to\my\app\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1774:21)
       at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (C:\path\to\my\app\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1715:21)
       at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (C:\path\to\my\app\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1692:19)
       at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (C:\path\to\my\app\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1637:21)
       at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (C:\path\to\my\app\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1620:21)
       at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (C:\path\to\my\app\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1597:21)
       at Parser.pp$3.parseExpression (C:\path\to\my\app\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1573:21)
       at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (C:\path\to\my\app\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:727:47)
       at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (C:\path\to\my\app\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:638:25)
       at Parser.parse (C:\path\to\my\app\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:516:17)
       at Object.parse (C:\path\to\my\app\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:3098:39)
       at Parser.parse (C:\path\to\my\app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Parser.js:902:15)
       at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (C:\path\to\my\app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:104:16)
       at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (C:\path\to\my\app\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
       at nextLoader (C:\path\to\my\app\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
       at C:\path\to\my\app\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
       at Storage.finished (C:\path\to\my\app\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
       at C:\path\to\my\app\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16
       at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:445:3)
    @ ./~/css-loader!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/sass-loader?sourceMap!./app/scss/application.scss 8:127867-127941 8:127964-128038
...
```

**/app/scss/application.scss**

```
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
@import "glyphicons-halflings"; // is no longer a separate node_module because that package is broken af (defining non-existent urls)
@import "~pace/themes/pace-theme-flash";
@import "~animate.css/animate";
@import "~awesome-bootstrap-checkbox/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox";
@import "~nouislider/distribute/nouislider.min.css";
@import "~bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select";
@import "~bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css";
@import "~ng2-dnd/bundles/style.css";

@import "custom-utils.scss";

// css overrides
@import "noUiSlider/_noUiSlider-overide.scss";
@import "nvd3/_nvd3-override.scss";
@import "angular2-grid/angular2-grid-override.scss";
@import "angular2-modal/_angular2-modal-override.scss";
@import "bootstrap-override";
@import "libs-override";

//
//end custom libs
//everything below this line is required for essential styling
@import "font";
@import "general";
@import "global-transitions";
@import "base";
@import "utils";
@import "print";
@import "dragula";
```

**/config/webpack.config.vendor.js**

```
/*
    After making changes to this file, you MUST re-build the vendor bundle 
*/

var isDevBuild = process.argv.indexOf("--env.prod") < 0;
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin("vendor.css");
var helpers = require("./helpers");

module.exports = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    resolve: {
        extensions: ["", ".json", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loaders: ["json-loader"],
                include: helpers.root("node_modules")
            },
            {
                test: /\.png(\?.*$|$)/,
                loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/png&name=img/[name].[ext]?[hash]",
                include: helpers.root("node_modules")
            },
            {
                test: /\.jpe?g(\?.*$|$)/,
                loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/jpeg&name=img/[name].[ext]?[hash]",
                include: helpers.root("node_modules")
            },
            {
                test: /\.gif(\?.*$|$)/,
                loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/gif&name=img/[name].[ext]?[hash]",
                include: helpers.root("node_modules")
            },
            {
                test: /\.ico(\?.*$|$)/,
                loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/x-icon&name=img/[name].[ext]?[hash]",
                include: helpers.root("node_modules")
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff2?(\?.*$|$)/,
                loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=fonts/[name].[ext]?[hash]",
                include: helpers.root("node_modules")
            },
            {
                test: /\.ttf(\?.*$|$)/,
                loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream&name=fonts/[name].[ext]?[hash]",
                include: helpers.root("node_modules")
            },
            {
                test: /\.eot(\?.*$|$)/,
                loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&name=fonts/[name].[ext]?[hash]",
                include: helpers.root("node_modules")
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg(\?.*$|$)/,
                loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml&name=img/[name].[ext]?[hash]",
                include: helpers.root("node_modules")
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss(\?|$)/,
                loader: extractCSS.extract(["css", "resolve-url", "sass?sourceMap"]),
                include: helpers.root("node_modules")
            },
            {
                test: /\.css(\?|$)/,
                loader: extractCSS.extract(["css"]),
                include: helpers.root("node_modules")
            }
        ]
    },
    entry: {
        vendor: [
            "@angular/common",
            "@angular/compiler",
            "@angular/core",
            "@angular/flex-layout",
            "@angular/forms",
            "@angular/http",
            "@angular/material",
            "@angular/platform-browser",
            "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic",
            "@angular/router",
            "angular2-contextmenu",
            "angular2-grid",
            "angular2-modal",
            "angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap",
            "angular2-notifications",
            "angular2-universal",
            "angular2-universal-polyfills",
            "angular2-universal-polyfills/browser",
            "angular2-uuid",
            "animate.css/animate.min.css",
            "ansi-html",
            "ansi-regex",
            "awesome-bootstrap-checkbox/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.css", // scss does not define variables it uses
            "bootstrap",
            "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
            "bootstrap-colorpicker",
            "bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.css",
            "bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css",
            "bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.css",
            "bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css",
            "d3",
            "dragula",
            "es6-promise",
            "es6-shim",
            "event-source-polyfill",
            "font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
            // glyphicions-halflings is incomplete, has references to non-existing files (must be overwritten)
            // "glyphicons-halflings/css/glyphicons-halflings.css",
            "html-entities",
            "jquery",
            "jquery.animate-number",
            "jquery-slimscroll",
            "jquery-slimscroll",
            "jquery-ui",
            "jquery-ui/ui/widgets/sortable",
            "lodash",
            "moment",
            "moment-timezone",
            "ng2-bootstrap",
            "ng2-cookies",
            "ng2-cookies",
            "ng2-cookies/ng2-cookies",
            "ng2-datetime",
            "ng2-datetime-picker",
            "ng2-dnd",
            "ng2-dnd/bundles/style.css",
            "ng2-dragula",
            "ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula",
            "ng2-file-upload",
            "ng2-nouislider",
            "ng2-pagination",
            "ng2-select2",
            "ng2-table",
            "nouislider",
            "nouislider/distribute/nouislider.css",
            "nouislider/distribute/nouislider.min.css",
            "nvd3",
            "nvd3/build/nv.d3.css",
            "pace/themes/pace-theme-flash.css",
            "primeng/primeng.js",
            "primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
            "primeng/resources/themes/bootstrap/theme.css",
            "querystring",
            "rxjs",
            "strip-ansi",
            "zone.js"
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: helpers.root("wwwroot", "dist"),
        filename: "[name].js",
        library: "[name]_[hash]"
    },
    plugins: [
        extractCSS,
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            // jquery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery",
            Tether: "tether",
            "window.Tether": "tether",
            Hammer: "hammerjs/hammer",
            Shuffle: "shufflejs",
            d3: "d3",
            Rickshaw: "rickshaw",
            nv: "nvd3",
            Raphael: "webpack-raphael",
            "window.Raphael": "webpack-raphael",
            Skycons: "skycons/skycons",
            Dropzone: "dropzone"
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.DllPlugin({
            path: helpers.root("wwwroot", "dist", "[name]-manifest.json"),
            name: "[name]_[hash]",
            context: helpers.root("node_modules")
        }),
        // HACK: make webpack exit with != 0 error code on error (when not in HMR/dev) https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/708
        function () {
            this.plugin("done", function (stats) {
                if (stats.compilation.errors && stats.compilation.errors.length && process.argv.indexOf("--watch") === -1) {
                    console.log(stats.compilation.errors);
                    process.exit(1); // or throw new Error("webpack build failed.");
                }
            });
        }
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            }
        })
    ])
};
```

My client config consists of these parts:

**/config/webpack.dev.js**

```
console.log("----> Development");
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var commonClientConfig = require('./webpack.common.client.js');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var clientBundleConfig = webpackMerge(commonConfig, commonClientConfig, {
    plugins: [
        // Plugins that apply in development builds only
        new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin(
            // the following did not work, but using no arguments works fine
            /*{
            filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
            moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(helpers.root('wwwroot','dist'), '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
    }*/)
]
});

module.exports = [clientBundleConfig];
```

**/config/webpack.common.js**

```
var helpers = require('./helpers');
var webpack = require("webpack");


module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts'],
        root: [
            helpers.root('app')
        ]
    },

    output: {
        publicPath: '/dist/', // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                include: [
                    helpers.root('app')
                ],
                loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/, // mostly angular templates
                include: helpers.root('app'),
                loader: 'html'
            },/*
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)(\?.*$|$)/,
                include: [
                    helpers.root('node_modules','font-awesome'),
                    helpers.root('node_modules','bootstrap')
                ],
                loader: 'file?name=vendor-missing/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },*/
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)(\?.*$|$)/,
                include: [
                    helpers.root('app'),
                ], // new
                loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                include: helpers.root('app'), // new
                // IMPORTANT: Sass/libsass do not provide url rewriting, all linked assets must be relative to the output. css loader can process generated css though
                /*loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
                    'style', // The backup style loader
                    'css?sourceMap!sass?sourceMap'
                )
                */
                // resolve-url needs source map to operate correctly, but then there's this issue of sourcemap urls not being generated correctly https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/232
                // loaders: ['raw', 'css', 'resolve-url', 'sass?sourceMap']
                loaders: ['to-string','css', 'resolve-url', 'sass?sourceMap']
                // loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css', 'resolve-url', 'sass?sourceMap']) // no hot module replacement!
            },{
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: helpers.root('app'),
                loader: 'to-string!css!resolve-url'
                // loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css','resolve-url']) // no HMR/hot

            }
        ]
    },

    htmlLoader: {
        ignoreCustomFragments: [/\{\{.*?}}/],
        // root: helpers.root(),
        root: helpers.root('app'),
        attrs: ['img:src', 'link:href']
    },

    plugins: [
    // plugins must always be defined, even if empty
    // https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/358
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            // jquery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            Tether: 'tether',
            'window.Tether': 'tether',
            Hammer: 'hammerjs/hammer',
            Shuffle: 'shufflejs',
            d3: 'd3',
            Rickshaw: 'rickshaw',
            nv: 'nvd3',
            Raphael: 'webpack-raphael',
            'window.Raphael': 'webpack-raphael',
            Skycons: 'skycons/skycons',
            Dropzone: 'dropzone'
        })
        // don't do workaround/hack for failed webpack here - dev might benefit from being able to keep service running
    ]
};
```

**/config/webpack.common.client.js**

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

var helpers = require('./helpers');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var commonClient = {
    entry: {
        'main-client': helpers.root('app', 'boot-client.ts')
    },

    output: {
        path: helpers.root('wwwroot', 'dist')
    },

    plugins: [

        // NOTE: each target folder must already exist!
        // We must copy these assets because they are referenced as hardcoded strings (without url or require). webpack cannot resolve these dependencies
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
            context: helpers.root('app', 'assets', 'img'),
            from: helpers.root('app', 'assets', 'img', '**', '*'),
            to: helpers.root('wwwroot', 'dist', 'assets', 'img')
        }],
        {
            debug: 'warning',
            copyUnmodified: false // TODO: set to true if not all files are watched
        }),

        // _Layout.cshtml relies on wwwroot/dist/assets/img/brand_small_black.ico
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
            context: helpers.root('app', 'assets', 'img'),
            from: helpers.root('app', 'assets', 'img', 'logo', 'brand_small_black.ico'),
            to: helpers.root('wwwroot', 'dist', 'assets', 'img', 'brand_small_black.ico')
        }],
        {
            debug: 'warning',
            copyUnmodified: false // TODO: set to true if not all files are watched
        }),

        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: helpers.root('node_modules'), // (absolute path) context of requests in the manifest (or content property)
            manifest: require('../wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json') // (object): an object containing content and name
            // manifest: require(helpers.root('wwwroot', 'dist', 'vendor-manifest.json'))
        }),
    ]
};

module.exports = commonClient;
```